# Use foreach with bootstrap's grid to list items

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I use a `foreach` to list a product list to simulate a store's catalog with this code

```
@foreach (var item in Model){
       <div class="col-md-4">    
            <div class="wp-block product">
                 <figure>
                        @*<img alt="" src="~/Images/20852816-6959-f6580ba5 (1).jpg" class="img-responsive img-center">*@
                                            <img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.Imagen, 0, item.Imagen.Length)" class="img-responsive img-center" />
                  </figure>
                  <h2 class="product-title"><a href="">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</a></h2>
                   <p>
                      Descripcion del producto
                  </p>
                  <div class="wp-block-footer">
                       <span class="price pull-left">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Precio)</span>
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-base btn-icon btn-cart pull-right">
                       <span>Add to cart</span>
                  </a>
          </div>
     </div>    
</div>
}
```

but with this I just have 3 column with 3 item, doesn't matter how much item i have, if i have 6 item, i need 3 columns in 2 row, but i not sure what element i have to modified with css or jQuery.

Comment: What does the rendered html look like for 6 items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this for your output. this will build a new row for every 3 items.

```
@{
    var itemCount = 0;
}

@{
    foreach (var item in Model.Reverse().Take(9))
    {
        var insertRow = itemCount % 3 == 0;

        if(insertRow)
        {
            @Html.Raw("<div class="row">
    ")
    }

                           <div class="col-md-4">
                               <div class="wp-block product">
                                   <figure>
                                       @*<img alt="" src="~/Images/20852816-6959-f6580ba5 (1).jpg" class="img-responsive img-center">*@
                                       <img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.Imagen, 0, item.Imagen.Length)" class="img-responsive img-center" />
                                   </figure>
                                   <h2 class="product-title"><a href="">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</a></h2>
                                   <p>
                                       Descripcion del producto
                                   </p>
                                   <div class="wp-block-footer">
                                       <span class="price pull-left">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Precio)</span>
                                       <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-base btn-icon btn-cart pull-right">
                                           <span>Add to cart</span>
                                       </a>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                           </div>

                               if (insertRow)
                               {
                               @Html.Raw("
                           </div>")
        }

        itemCount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your content inside a row, see following example

```
 <div class="container" style="width: 800px">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-4">.col-md-4</div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">.col-md-4</div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">.col-md-4</div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">.col-md-4</div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">.col-md-4</div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">.col-md-4</div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">.col-md-4</div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">.col-md-4</div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">.col-md-4</div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">.col-md-4</div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">.col-md-4</div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">.col-md-4</div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/arc0g6ys/

```
<div class="container" style="width: your container with better to create a new class">
  <div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in Model){ 
       ...
    }
  </div>
</div>
```